# LINQ to XML doesn't return default value

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a default value specified in XSD as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="image">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="imageType" default="normal" />
</xs:complexType>
```

But unless I explicitly include a value in the XML, 'type' is always returned as an empty string when I run a LINQ query such as this:

```
Dim images = From i In collection.<image> Select i.@path, i.@type
```

Should this be expected or is it possible to omit the attribute and let LINQ check for a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well do you first validate the input XML against your schema? 
Here is an example:

```
Dim xrs As New XmlReaderSettings()
xrs.Schemas.Add(Nothing, "..\..\XMLSchema1.xsd")
xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema

Dim doc As XDocument

Using xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("..\..\XMLFile1.xml", xrs)
    doc = XDocument.Load(xr)
End Using

For Each img As XElement In doc.<images>.<image>
    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", img.@type)
Next
```

With the schema being

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="images">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="image">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" default="normal"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the XML input being

```
<images>
  <image/>
  <image type="vector"/> 
</images>
```

that sample outputs

```
Type: normal
Type: vector
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, spot on! I'd figured that the LINQ would have validated the XML against the schema specified with the xsi:schemaLocation attribute